# Combinatorial way of managing a store's cashier

Tags: combinatorics

I came across a nice question.

> A certain store sells tickets for POP concerts and Rock concerts.
>   a POP concert ticket's price is 50 dollars, and a Rock concert ticket's price is 10 euros.
>   200 people are interested in buying a ticket for a POP concert, and 100 of those have a 50 dollar bill and the other 100 have a 100 dollar bill.
>   150 OTHER people are interested to buy a ticket for a Rock concert, where 80 of them has a bill of 10 euros and the other 70 have a bill of 20 euros.
>   At the start of the day, the cashier in the store is empty (no money.)
>   In how many ways can we arrange the 350 people in queue, that each one of them can get an exact excess to their money?

I've been thinking about it for two days now and I haven't even reached a clue on how to start solving it!

EDIT: Here's what I came up with so far:

Let us divide the problem into two sub-problems:

> Product I: 50d. 200 customers. 100 have 50d (no change required) and 100 have 100d (50d change required. Let us consider the 100 who have 50d as red balls, and the 100 who have 100d as blue balls. At any given time, in a sorted line, red balls $\geq$ blue balls.

And

> Product I: 10e. 150 customers. 80 have 10e (no change required) and 70 have 20e (10e change required. Let us consider the 80 who have 10e as white squares, and the 70 who have 20e as grey squares. At any given time, in a sorted line, white squares $\geq$ grey squares.

We should calculate the two above problems perhaps using Catalan's numbers (it reminds me of Catalan). And then, somehow, mix both balls and squares to be sorted in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the store conveniently deals in euros and dollars separately, let us concentrate on arranging just the ROCK folks independently.

Since the store starts out empty, we need to arrange the people, so that at any given time the number holding $10$ euros is $\ge$ the number holding $20$ euros.

This is a classic application of [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number): you view it as a walk on grid, such that you need to stay below the diagonal.

I will leave the rest to you.

Comment: Wow, I just edited the question and entered this since I have thought about it!!!

Comment: @TheNotMe: Yeah it happens :-) You hit upon a solution when you write out the question...

Comment: One thing. Let us say using Catalan I calculated the two sub problems.
There is still on how to mix them together in one line which can be tricky. Any ideas?

Comment: @TheNotMe: Multiply by the number of ways you can do POP, with ROCK, with the number of ways to interleave them. You have x ROCK, y POP and you can interleave in $\binom{x+y}{x}$ ways.

Comment: But one can also return 5 bills of 10 dollars to a POP person. This changes the total number of possibilities.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Dollars and Euros make the problem simpler, assuming no exchange rate issues :-)

Comment: Ah yes of course. I should read more carefully. Otherwise, I imagine that would be a nasty recursion or count of 4D paths...

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Yeah, that would be one nasty problem...

Comment: Haha thank God it is a seperate problem.
@Aryabhata perhaps I just consider there are 350 places, first I count the ways I can sort Rockees (With the limitation using Catalan) in 350 places in the queue. and then for the 150 POPees how to sort them in a queue of 150 places with the limitation. Perhaps that would work? (multiplying them)

Comment: @TheNotMe: Yes, that should work too.